# C# Extracting date from an object in an expression builder

Tags: c#, datetime, azure-cosmosdb

I have a collection in Cosmos DocumentDB, where we introduced a field called `CustomParams`. It is the serialized form of `Dictionary<string, object>`. The idea is to accommodate custom values of any kind that would vary from one document to another. This design is out of my hands and can't be changed.

We have a Query endpoint for our api that builds an expression tree(predicate) and runs it against this container to produce results. There is now an ask  to add to the query(filtering for a specific date field in the `Dictionary<string, object>`). The problem is that since the value is an object, I try to convert it into a DateTime using the `DateTime.Parse(customParams[key]!.ToString())` and compare it against the datetime that was passed into our api, but Cosmos is unhappy and gives a `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Linq.DocumentQueryException: Method 'Parse' is not supported.` when I try to add this to the expression tree.

I changed my approach and tried to compare them as strings `customParams[key]!.ToString() == request.TargetDate.ToString()` in the predicate - while cosmos is happy with this, it does not give back the desired result, as the object to DateString conversion is producing a date string which is not the same as the date string produced from the request - and moreover feels like a error-prone hack.

So I've had to resort to taking this logic out of the expression tree, but instead keep my old expression tree to produce the results(we convert it into a IReadOnlyCollection) and then do a post-processing on the collection.

In short, this is the code snippet I had to take out of the expression tree and run as post processing on the collection:

```
private static bool DoesTargetDateMatch(OrderItem orderItem, IOrderedPagedQuery request)
{
    return request.TargetDate != null &&
        orderItem.CustomParams != null &&
        orderItem.CustomParams.TryGetValue("Target Date", out var targetDate) &&
        targetDate != null &&
        DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Parse(targetDate.ToString()!)) == DateOnly.FromDateTime(request.TargetDate!.Value);
}
```

Is there anyway to accommodate this in the predicate itself, which does not feel hacky and avoids the post processing entirely?

Comment: I've used this approach to model custom data. I'd suggest moving away from Linq-based queries if at all possible and use `QueryDefinition` instead to build your queries. This gives full flexibility and avoids the internals of Linq expressions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should restructure the query to use `is` operator.

Option1:

```
    private static bool DoesTargetDateMatch(OrderItem orderItem, IOrderedPagedQuery request)
    {
        if (request.TargetDate > DateTime.MinValue && request.TargetDate < DateTime.MaxValue)
        {
            //targetdate is valid

            //now check with CustomParams
            if (orderItem.CustomParams.TryGetValue("Target Date", out object d) && d is DateTime)
            {
                return (DateTime)d == request.TargetDate;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Option 2:

```
    private static bool DoesTargetDateMatch(OrderItem orderItem, IOrderedPagedQuery request)
    {
        if (request.TargetDate is DateTime)
        {
            //targetdate is valid

            //now check with CustomParams
            if (orderItem.CustomParams.TryGetValue("Target Date", out object d) && d is DateTime)
            {
                return (DateTime)d == request.TargetDate;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but how does this enable me run this as part of the expression tree? Are you suggesting this as an independent option for best practice or would this enable me to run this as part of the expression tree?

Comment: @Sai - May be I didn't understand your question correctly..  have you pasted the code which builds the expression tree?